# How to add a custom text field to a UIAlertController

Tags: swift, uialertcontroller

I have a text field class that suggests values as one types.

It is easy to add a (standard) text field to the UIAlertController using:

alertController.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler()

But how to I add an instance of the custom text field class to the alert controller?

Comment: All I could do is to change the textField properties this way:
`alertController.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler{
            textField -> Void in
            textField.textColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
        }`
You can even change the textField's inputView if you want to create a special input method like a pickerview or a custom UIView. You mentioned custom text field, if it is an already existing class derived from UITextField, then my solution is not working

Comment: It is unfortunately an already existing class, derived from UITextField. In the end I used a custom AlertView - which is a brilliant piece of work BTW - [SCLAlertView](https://github.com/dogo/SCLAlertView). There I could make use of the custom text field.

Comment: Nice work! Your cusom alertview looks great!

Comment: Wish it was mine. I simply used it - did not create it unfortunately :-) But I agree, it does look great.